# multiple image uploader from single image uploader

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

I am creating a component in joomla using component creator. In this component I want to upload multiple images at a time instead of just a single image. What do I need to change in the following code in order to do this?

```
          <?php if (!empty($item->images)):
         $uploadPath = 'components' . '/'. 'com_gallery' . '/' . 'img' .'/' .$item->images;        
       echo '<a href="' . JRoute::_(JUri::base() . $uploadPath, false) . '" target="_blank" title="See the images">' . $item->images . '</a>';
          else:
            echo $item->images;
            endif; ?>               </td>
```

Comment: For a SO question, you will get much more help from people if you can show what things you have tried, what resources you have read etc. The above is a good start, but what have you researched so far? Do you know if it's even possible to do what you are asking, or is that an additional question to be asked?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use the core field since it already supports that?

Comment: core field means i didnt understand?

Comment: sir actually it default coding of that component

Comment: Are you trying to do this in the frontend, backend view or backend-options (as a form field) ? If it's a form field, then you could just use this in your XML file `<field name="myimage" type="media" directory="stories" />`

Comment: i am use this in backend ,for uploding multiple images so that i can show it on frontend